# java, A window with 2 buttons

Tags: java, swing

What i want to do is have my program stop, and then open a new "window" with 2 buttons. It would be very similar to the command "JOptionPane.showInputDialog()" except i don't want a text-input, and i want the buttons to say yes and no. clicking either button should then output the value yes or no.

Thank you very much

```
public class example {
  System.out.println("was this helpful?");
  String answer = code.that.makes.it.work;
  System.out.println(answer);
}
```

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html There you go... shows you everything you need to know. Literally right on the page.

Comment: You can try               `String answer =  JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "", "Choose", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION)==JOptionPane.YES_OPTION?"yes": "no";`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It would be very similar to the command "JOptionPane.showInputDialog()" except i don't want a text-input, and i want the buttons to have say yes and no

Then you can use:

```
int response = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(...);
```

or

```
int response = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(...);
```

The response will indicate the button that was clicked.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Make Dialogs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html) for more information and examples.